# How to convert a hex string to an integer?

Tags: python, raspberry-pi

I wrote the following code to send and receive data through the serial port on a Raspberry PI.

```
import serial
serial=serial.Serial("dev/ttyAMA0",
                baudrate=9600,
                stopbits=serial.STOPBITS_ONE,
                parity=serial.PARITY_NONE,
                bytesize=serial.EIGHTBITS,
                timeout=0.5)

 chuoi="\xAA\xOO\x03\x25\x26\x00\x00\xBB"
 while 1: 
    serial.write(chuoi)
    data=serial.readline()
    print int(data,16)
```

I get the following error:

```
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 16: '\xaa\x00\x02\x01\x83\x80\xbb'
```

How do I convert this hex string to an integer?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The value you have is a byte string, not hex.  You can encode it to hex then interpret that as a base 16 number.  Assuming the return value is meant to be interpreted as one number, and knowing nothing about the format, such as little endian vs big endian, and assuming the `\xoo` was a typo for `\x00`.

```
from binascii import hexlify

data = serial.readline()
hex = hexlify(data)
num = int(hex, 16)

print(num)
```

Answer (score 0):

The second byte in the string chuoi is `\xOO` - it comprises of the letter `O` rather than the digit 0. That is causing your error.